# VirtualBox cloned Ubuntu Server network error

Tags: networking, virtualbox, mac-address

I run a number of virtual servers on my network and I want to be able to easily clone base installations of Ubuntu Server. I use the VBoxManage command to clone the actual hard disk and I then create a new profile for my VM and copy over the settings of the original VM.

However, when I boot into the cloned VM, there seems to be a network problem. When I issue a PING I get the message "`Network unreachable`". I traced it down to the fact that the virtual network card of the cloned VM has a different MAC address then the original VM. When I copy the MAC address the clone seems to work fine.

How can I have the cloned VM have it's own MAC address?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just remove `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` then restart.
And all will be fine.

Comment: Correct and spot on, +1

Comment: I'll mention that if you're importing via VBoxManage you may also have to reset the mac address using `VBoxManage modifyvm MyVM --macaddress1 auto`

Comment: The file comes up again on reboot. I am on Ubuntu 12.04.